# Какой вариант лучше чтобы вывести список с pagination?

Tags: android

a) Через paged list

1. Загрузить весь список с сервера
2. Сохранить в базу данных
3. Вывести список из базы данных через PagedList

b) С сервера используя pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Правильного" способа нет. Всё зависит от того как вам нужно. Если нужно чтобы работало без сети - пишите в БД. Если надо, чтобы и из БД выводилось порциями - выводите порциями. Если это не нужно - выводите сразу всё, что есть в БД. Если оффлайн доступ не нужен - не пишите в БД, выводите что с сервера пришло. А можно сделать и так и этак - по какому-то условию выводить всё/порциями из БД или не трогать БД и использовать только то, что с сети пришло.